# Adding up every 5 lines of integers

Tags: scripting, numeric-data

I am writing a parser, and have to do some fancy stuff. I am trying not to use python, but I might have to at this point.

Given an STDOUT that looks like this:

```
1
0
2
3
0
0
1
0
0
2
0
3
0
4
0
5
0
2
.
.
.
```

For 100,000 lines. What I need to do is add up every 5, like so:

```
1 - start
0 |
2 | - 6 
3 |
0 - end
0 - start
1 |
0 | - 3
0 |
2 - end
0 - start
3 |
0 | - 7
4 |
0 - end
5 
0 
2 
. 
.
.
```

The `-`, `|`, `start`, `end`, are all for visual representation, I just need it in a column list:

```
 6
 3
 7
 .
 .
 .
```

I currently have a method of doing this by using an incremental `head -n $i` and `tail -n 5` to cut 5 rows out of the list, then I use `paste -sd+ - | bc` to add up all the values. But this is wayyyy to slow because there are 100,000 lines.

How can I do this better?

Comment: 100,000 columns or lines?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, based on the working commands OP is currently using, it can only be lines.

Comment: "But this is wayyyy to slow because there is 100,000 columns"

Comment: And the title says columns

Comment: @JeffSchaller, there, all better.  :)  I don't see how there could be *any* doubt about which was meant, given the sample input and output and the use of `head` and `tail` and `paste -s`.

Comment: Thanks, @Wildcard! I just like words to mean what they're supposed to mean. Helps future searchers, too.

Comment: Are there *about* 100,000 lines, or exactly 100,00? What to do with extras, if any?

Comment: Sorry it is lines; my math TA has dyslexia and cannot discern from things moving in or out. I don't have dyslexia haha. You guys fixed my post, I greatly appreciate that and all of the feedback. This code is for a parser on a particle research project. I am constantly amazed by the community of thinkers and their willingness to help, collaborate and create. Thank you.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, in this case there are over 100,000 but the number of rows modulo 5 is zero always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat numbers.txt | awk '{sum += $1; if (NR % 5 == 0) {print sum; sum=0}} END {if (NR % 5 != 0) print sum}'
```

`sum` starts as 0 in awk. Every fifth line it prints the current sum of numbers out, then resets the sum to zero and goes over the next five lines. The `END` at the end handles the edge case of the number of lines in the file not being a multiple of five, eg if there's 18 lines in the file it will print the sum of the last 3 lines. It also handles the edge case of not printing a unwanted zero when the number of lines is a multiple of five.

Comment: But if there are twenty lines you will get an extra 0 at the end.

Comment: @Wildcard good point. I updated the answer for that edge case too.

Comment: Or just use `cat numbers.txt | awk '((NR-1) % 5 == 0 && NR > 1) {print sum; sum=0} {sum += $1} END {print sum}'`

Comment: Or: `cat numbers.txt | awk 'NR==1{sum=$1;next} ((NR-1) % 5 == 0) {print sum; sum=0} {sum += $1} END {print sum}'`  :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '$!N;$!N;$!N;$!N;s/\n/+/g' list.txt | bc
```

Demonstration:

```
$ seq 33 | sed '$!N;$!N;$!N;$!N;s/\n/+/g'
1+2+3+4+5
6+7+8+9+10
11+12+13+14+15
16+17+18+19+20
21+22+23+24+25
26+27+28+29+30
31+32+33
$ seq 33 | sed '$!N;$!N;$!N;$!N;s/\n/+/g' | bc
15
40
65
90
115
140
96
$
```

This approach has several advantages:

1. Simple
2. Fast
3. Cleanly separates number grouping from the math
4. Correctly handles cases of 0 rows, 1 row, 5n rows, and non-multiple-of-5 rows

---

If you want to discard extras (e.g. discard 31 through 33 in the above example), you can do away with all the `$!` conditions; this is the simpler command and was my first attempt:

```
$ seq 33 | sed 'N;N;N;N;s/\n/+/g'
1+2+3+4+5
6+7+8+9+10
11+12+13+14+15
16+17+18+19+20
21+22+23+24+25
26+27+28+29+30
$
```

Comment: No need for cat. Just do `sed '$!N;$!N;$!N;$!N;s/\n/+/g' infile | bc`

Comment: @Arrow, true, but the OP said a STDOUT with the numbers, so I was using `cat` as a stand-in for whatever command generated the output.  But then, OP also described using `head` and `tail` multiple times, which wouldn't have worked in a pipeline—so you're right, OP must be using a file; I'll make that edit.

Answer (score 2):

and a shell loop (no error-checking; assumes an even multiple of 5 numbers):

```
while read a; do read b; read c; read d; read e; echo $((a+b+c+d+e)); done < input
```

Comment: Takes 1.5 seconds on a 100.000 lines file. Not that bad.

Comment: Reminds me of a UNIX quote: "Never write it in C if you can do it in awk; Never do it in awk if sed can handle it; Never use sed when tr can do the job; Never invoke tr when cat is sufficient; Avoid using cat whenever possible."

Comment: Well, it is still 10 times longer than a pure awk solution (yes even redirecting output to /dev/null). In any case, where could I put the command `column` (or `paste` or `pr`) in that quote? Around `tr`, maybe? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If your data has an exact multiple of 5 lines, you could modify your `head` / `tail` shell loop + `paste` command to use `paste` alone i.e.

```
yourcommand | paste -d+ - - - - | bc
```

A better option might be to use the `pr` paginator to arrange the output into 5 columns separated by `+`

```
yourcommand | pr -ats+ -5 | bc
```

- `-a` print columns across rather than down
- `-t` omit page headers and footers
- `-s+` set the column separator to `+` in place of the default tab

Unlike `paste`, `pr` does the right thing in the case of incomplete rows e.g. using `cat STDOUT` to simulate your command output

```
$ cat STDOUT | pr -ats+ -5
1+0+2+3+0
0+1+0+0+2
0+3+0+4+0
5+0+2
```

whence

```
$ cat STDOUT | pr -ats+ -5 | bc
6
3
7
7
```

---

The `rs` command seems like another good candidate however the obvious `rs -C+ 0 5` seems to want to add trailing delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

firstly because this just calls for xargs:

```
<file xargs -rn5 perl -e 'foreach(@ARGV){$a+$_};print $a,"\n"'
```

but for speed you really want to minimize the number of interpreter invocations so I would use

```
perl -e 'while(!eof(ARGV){print <>+<>+<>+<>+<>,"\n"}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You may convert the values list into lines with 5 values with `column`.
Assuming tabs are 8 spaces (and values are smaller than that):

```
$ column -c 40 -x infile
1       2       3       4       5
6       7       8       9       10
1       0       2       3       0
0       1       0       0       2
0       3       0       4       0
5       0       2
```

And translate each tab to a + to feed bc:

```
$ column -c 40 -x infile | tr '\t' '+'
1+2+3+4+5
6+7+8+9+10
1+0+2+3+0
0+1+0+0+2
0+3+0+4+0
5+0+2

$ column -c 40 -x infile | tr '\t' '+' | bc
15
40
6
3
7
7
```

Maybe awk will be better:

```
$ column -c 40 -x infile | awk '{print($1+$2+$3+$4+$5)}'
15
40
6
3
7
7
```

That-s only one call to each program, both programs will start at the same time due to the pipe and will work in parallel.

Timing gives me (in a very slow CPU) only 0.350 seconds for a 100000 lines file.

And only 0.148 seconds if the result goes to a file (not screen).

Yes, this handles incomplete lines, a file that ends in 1, 2, 3, or 4 numbers.
This will work correctly if numbers are smaller than 1.000.000.

Bigger numbers (up to a sum of (2^62)-1 9223372036854775807 ~9e18 in a 64 bit system) will need something like:

```
$ xargs -n 5 -a infile| awk '{print($1+$2+$3+$4+$5)}'
```

But that is quite slower (38.8 seconds), switching to pure awk

```
$ awk '{s+=$0};NR%5{next};!(NR%5){print(s);s=0}END{if(s){print(s)}}' infile
```

Or, if you need a pipe, use:

```
$ cat infile | awk '{s+=$0};NR%5{next};!(NR%5){print(s);s=0}END{if(s){print(s)}}'
```

Takes about 0.150 seconds, That seems fast enough to me.